# If 3 columns in Access contain the same value, how would I add an extra column to show the whether the data in the 3 columns are the same

Tags: sql, ms-access

If I have 3 columns which has data in it. How would I add an extra column next to it stating whether the data is the same. Please see below for example:

[image]

The table above is the answer I require.

Answer (score 0):

Try `CASE..WHEN..THEN` like below:

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN field1 = field2 AND field2 = field3 THEN 'Equal' 
       ELSE 'Not Equal'
       END AS 'EqualityTest'
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Thank you. If I were to skip using Access and use Excel instead. But this time I want to find a value within the data. For example, I want to look for "Pass" in this sentence "Pass - The delivery has been made". How would I go about doing this knowing I have 3 columns which has pass and fail statements.

Comment: In ms access, you could use `SELECT instr(mycolumn, "Pass") > 0 FROM mytable;`

Comment: `CASE WHEN` is not available in MS Access (Jet/ACE SQL dialect). Use the `IIF()` function. And second solution requires an ADO connection to workbook to use SQL on Excel spreadsheets.